# Inconsistent type conversion in python/numpy when using scalars or lists/arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, floating-point, type-conversion

I have a question about the strange way python/numpy performs type conversion. When I perform an arithmetic operation between a float32 and a float64 number, the lower precision is converted to float64 and then the operation is performed and the result will be in float64. But when a list or a numpy array consists of float32 numbers, this type conversion is performed in a reverse direction, i.e. this time it is the float64 number that is down converted to a float 32 number.

```
>> a = numpy.float32(10.0)
>> b = numpy.float64(1.0)
>> (a/b).dtype
   dtype('float64')
>> (numpy.array([a])/b).dtype
   dtype('float32')
>> (numpy.array([a])/b).dtype
   dtype('float32')
```

I think this different behaviour is inconsistent and can cause bugs in programs. This was a source of a bug in my code when I had an array of float32. See the different results in the following example:

```
>> a = numpy.float32(9.4247779)
>> print a % numpy.pi  # note: numpy.pi is of type float64
   2.3849761277e-08
>> aArr = numpy.array([a])
>> print aArr % numpy.pi
   [ 3.1415925]
```

Can one tell me why python/Numpy does the type conversions differently? Is it something deliberately implemented? How one can force python/numpy to treat lists/numpy arrays the same that it treats numbers?

Comment: That's an intentional feature of Numpy. Bear in mind that Numpy is a 3rd-party library, it's not a standard Python library, and the Numpy developers are free to make Numpy behave however they like.

Comment: @PM2Ring if it's intentional, do you know the rational behind that decision?

Comment: @JulienBernu I am not a Numpy developer, but I assume that it's done like that for reasons of efficiency. Numpy arrays are supposed to be homogeneous, so if you want to promote one member of an array you really should promote the whole array, and obviously that's not a cheap operation, since it requires building a whole new array with the new dtype. So if you want to operate on a float32 array & get a float64 array as the result then you need to do that explicitly.

Comment: @PM2Ring efficiency was my first guess also, but if it so, it is coming with a big price of inconsistency! functions will work differently for inputs of scalar type and array type. From now on I have to check everywhere if the variable is scalar or an array to avoid getting a surprise.

Comment: Well, if you want the speed benefits that Numpy arrays can give you, you need to use them properly. :)

Comment: Usually we use `np.array(.., dtype=...)` rather than `np.float32(..)` directly.  Indexing an array may produce an object of that type, but creating such type directly is rarely useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a case where scalars do not promote arrays. Observe that

```
# scalar / scalar
>>> (a/b).dtype
dtype('float64')

# array / scalar, array.dtype wins
>>> (np.asarray([a])/b).dtype
dtype('float32')

>>> np.asarray([a]).dtype
dtype('float32')

# array / array, usual promotion rules
>>> (np.asarray([a])/np.asarray([b])).dtype
dtype('float64')
```

**EDIT** https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.result_type.html#numpy.result_type

Comment: This pretty much repeats the op's observation without answering the question "why such inconsistency?"

Comment: The answer that OP wants is still not there, but at the end of the link. Could you write the essential parts of it in here.

Answer (score 0):

When you operate two scalars or two arrays the one with less precision is upcast:

```
>>> (a / b).dtype
dtype('float64')
>>> (numpy.array([a])/numpy.array([b])).dtype
dtype('float64')
```

When you operate an array and a scalar the type of the array is preserved:

```
>>> (numpy.array([a]) / b).dtype
dtype('float32')
>>> (a / np.array([b])).dtype
dtype('float64')
```

Comment: This pretty much repeats the op's observation without answering the question "why such inconsistency?"

Answer (score 0):

Why answers like this can't, technically, be answered without direct quotes from the documentation, or from developer's discussions.  Without those the best we can do it offer rationalizations - and illustrations of why the current practice makes sense.

Reading this on a tablet without access to an interpreter, I found the discussion confusing.  With an interpreter at hand I'll try to make some sense of it.  (and it will be edited several times).

First we need to be clear about the identity of various objects.

A `list` really doesn't belong in the discussion.  If it works in a calculation it's because it was converted into an array with the default dtypes:

```
In [255]: np.array([1,2,3]).dtype
Out[255]: dtype('int32')
In [256]: np.array([1.,2,3]).dtype
Out[256]: dtype('float64')
```

We also need to be careful about the distinctions between Python scalars and the various `np.float...()` (and int) objects. The later are called `array scalars`, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.scalars.html

Keep in mind that `float64` is a subclass of `float` (among other things):

```
In [258]: np.float64.__mro__
Out[258]: 
(numpy.float64,
...,
 numpy.generic,
 float,
 object)
```

It makes a lot of sense that multiplication of an array by a scalar should not change the result's dtype - unless absolutely necessary (e.g. multiplication by a float forces a change to float)

```
In [259]: 3*np.array([1,2],np.int32)
Out[259]: array([3, 6])
In [260]: 3*np.array([1,2],np.int16)
Out[260]: array([3, 6], dtype=int16)
In [261]: 3.0*np.array([1,2],np.int16)
Out[261]: array([ 3.,  6.])
In [262]: _.dtype
Out[262]: dtype('float64')
In [263]: 3.0*np.array([1,2],np.float16)
Out[263]: array([ 3.,  6.], dtype=float16)
```

We want to write:

```
arr = np.array([1,2,3], np.int16)
arr2 = 2*arr
```

without worrying that this simple scaling will change the dtype.

Casting involving several arrays is more complicated, but generally well defined.  Tools like `result_type` are available if you have questions.  And it's easy to experiment in an interactive shell.

The other clear case is pure Python operations - `numpy` has nothing to do with that. `int*int->int`, `int*float->float` etc.

A Python scalar operating on an array scalar is more complicated, and, I think at the heart of this question.

```
In [264]: 3*np.int16(3)
Out[264]: 9
In [265]: type(_)
Out[265]: numpy.int32
In [266]: 3*np.array(3, np.int16)
Out[266]: 9
In [267]: type(_)
Out[267]: numpy.int32
```

`np.int16` behaves the same as a 0d array of the same dtype.  From the docs:

> Array scalars have exactly the same methods as arrays. The default behavior of these methods is to internally convert the scalar to an equivalent 0-dimensional array and to call the corresponding array method.

```
In [270]: 3*np.array(3, np.int64)
Out[270]: 9
In [271]: type(_)
Out[271]: numpy.int64
```

It looks as though the scalar is converted to the default numpy type, and then the array/array casting rules apply.  (are there counter examples?)

I don't usually expect to see expressions like

```
x = np.float32(12.34)
```

in working code. There might be some valid uses, but normally `numpy` is used to create and manipulate multi-element arrays.  Python scalars are usually sufficient when for other uses - including scaling arrays.

By the way, `np.pi` is not a `np.float64`; it's a plain float, without `dtype` or other `numpy` attributes.

```
In [278]: type(np.pi)
Out[278]: float
```

More exploration of the `pi` calculations:

```
In [281]: pi3=9.4247779
In [282]: type(pi3)
Out[282]: float
In [283]: pi3 % np.pi
Out[283]: 3.1415925928204143
In [284]: type(_)
Out[284]: float       # scalar float * float => float
```

The same thing with an array:

```
In [285]: np.array([pi3]).dtype
Out[285]: dtype('float64')            # default array from list
In [286]: np.array([pi3]) % np.pi
Out[286]: array([ 3.14159259])
In [287]: _.item()               # express array element as scalar
Out[287]: 3.1415925928204143
```

The same thing with a `np.float32` dtype introduces a rounding error.

`np.float32(pi3)%np.pi` is also a result of the `float32` rounding, but apparently the order of calculation is different (I haven't worked out the details):

```
In [311]: np.array(pi3,np.float32) % np.pi 
Out[311]: 2.384976127700611e-08
In [312]: np.array(pi3,np.float32) - pi3
Out[312]: 8.4619140139352567e-08

In [316]: np.array([pi3],np.float32).item() - pi3
Out[316]: 8.461914013935257e-08
In [318]: (np.array([pi3],np.float32)%np.pi).item()
Out[318]: 3.141592502593994
In [319]: (np.array([pi3], np.float32).astype(np.float64) % np.pi).item()
Out[319]: 2.384976127700611e-08
```

So `% np.pi` on a `np.float32` is the same extracting that number to a scalar, and performing the `%` with Python scalars.  The 'error' is the result of converting `pi3` to `float32`.

```
In [353]: np.float32(pi3) % np.pi
Out[353]: 2.384976127700611e-08
In [354]: np.array([pi3], np.float32).item() % np.pi
Out[354]: 2.384976127700611e-08
```

compare that with the result of performing the calculation with both values `float32`:

```
In [356]: np.float32(pi3) % np.float32(np.pi)
Out[356]: 3.1415925
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually I also have mentioned in the question that the 'error' is the result of the conversion to 'float32'. My question is why down-conversion?! While usually (also observable in your examples) the  variables and results are elevated to occupy higher number of bits to avoid loss of precision.

Comment: The loss of precision occurs when we create a float32 from `pi3`. Upcasting it to `64` for `%pi` does not restore the lost digits.  The correct `%` uses a downcast `pi`.  Compare `int(pi3)%np.pi` with `int(pi3)%int(np.pi)`; `9%3.1415` vs. `9%3`.